# How to tell if an EXE is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, computer-architecture, cpu-architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quick way to tell if an installed application is 64-bit or 32-bit](https://superuser.com/questions/103071/quick-way-to-tell-if-an-installed-application-is-64-bit-or-32-bit)

What's the easiest way to know if a Windows EXE is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: A valid x64 binary will fail to run (on 32-bit Windows) with a "Not a valid Win32 application" error. However, this is hardly the best way to test as you can get the error for other reasons (file corruption, etc).

Comment: Refer :: http://superuser.com/questions/103071/quick-way-to-tell-if-an-installed-application-is-64-bit-or-32-bit