# How to check if a binary is 32 or 64 bit on Windows?

Tags: windows, binary-files, 32-vs-64-bit

Is there an easy way to check if a binary is 32 or 64 bit on Windows? I need to check before I move the program to a 32bit machine and experience a spectacular failure.

Comment: [This question is similar](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6040/8247), however it requires some work to check it.

Comment: @Guillaume: Executable images are not processes. Task Manager only shows processes.

Comment: [How do I determine whether an application I am installing is 32bit or 64bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1858358/995714)

Comment: It's weird that right click on the file > Properties doesn't give this information

Answer (score 599, accepted):

After examining header values from [Richard's answer](https://superuser.com/a/358459/341852), I came up with a solution which is fast, easy, and only requires a text editor. Even Windows' default notepad.exe would work.

1. Open the executable in a text editor. You might have to drag-and-drop or use
   the editor's `Open...` dialog, because Windows doesn't show `Open with...` option in the context menu for executables.
2. Check the first printable characters after the first occurrence of `PE`. This part is most likely to be surrounded by at least some whitespace (could be a lot of it), so it can be easily done visually.

Here is what you're going to find:

### 32-bit:

```
PE  L
```

### 64-bit:

```
PE  d†
```

**A word of warning:** using default Notepad on big files can be very slow, so better not use it for files larger than a megabyte or a few. In my case, it took about 30 seconds to display a 12 MiB file. Notepad++, however, was able to display a 120 MiB executable almost instantly.

This is solution might be useful in case you need to inspect a file on a machine you can't install any additional software on.

## Additional info:

If you have a HEX-Editor available, the offset of PE Signature is located at offset `0x3C`. The signature is `PE\0\0` (letters "P" and "E" followed by two null bytes), followed by a two-byte Machine Type in Little Endian.

The relevant values are `0x8664` for a 64-bit executable and `0x014c` for a 32-bit one (`64 86` and `4c 01` respectively when adjusted for endianness, but any decent hex editor will automatically handle endianness when you search for a hex value). There are a lot more possible values, but you probably won't ever encounter any of these, or be able to run such executables on your Windows PC.

Full list of machine types, along with the rest of .exe specifications, can be found in [Microsoft PE and COFF Specification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#machine-types) **Machine Types** section.

Comment: Hey, this is rather hacky. And for the better, since this actually appears to be the fastest and easiest solution for the vast majority of cases :)

Comment: Rare instance when notepad beat notepad++. Notepad shows this right, in notepad you have mess around with encoding to get it to show but it worked!

Comment: @zadane that's interesting. In my experience, Notepad++ would always use ANSI encoding when opening executables.Though it definitely does make it somewhat more difficult to find the needed fragment by showing zero bytes as `NUL` instead of whitespace.

Comment: Here is Java code that does the check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35418180/875305

Comment: I found PE ]_ÙV in a 32 bit WPF application.

Comment: @AnotherDayAnotherRob that's interesting. Technically, machine type is the two bytes after `PE\0\0`, so, assuming space in your comment is the two `\0` bytes the value would be `0x5F5D` (`5D 5F` if you open in HEX-editor due to endianness). There is nothing resembling that value in [Microsoft PE and COFF Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) (section 2.3.1. Machine Types). Are you sure you were looking in the right place?

Comment: @AlexanderRevo my bad, I had another look at the file and it's PE  L ]_ÙV   (whitespace is non printable chars)  I didn't spot the L first time.  Have an upvote.

Comment: I have my own program compiled (with Delphi) as 32/64 bit and the header is identical !!! So, it this method is not working always!

Comment: @SolarWind there's no such thing as 32/64 bit executable on Windows. You're probably compiling it as 32-bit, which would work on both 32 and 64 bit systems. 64-bit Windows can run 32-bit programs just fine.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo: There is a compile option *AnyCPU* in Visual Studio. If this was the same as compiling for 32bit, why would they add this third option?

Comment: @CoDEmanX this option means the IDE or JIT makes the choice for you. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/516730/3811791) or this [blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/) for more details.

Comment: This is a fairly brittle solution. If you understand PE images, you should immediately see, that the first clear-text `PE` you find in a file may not actually be the PE header. Besides, without a documented contract, nothing of this is reliable, not today and certainly not for the future. Sorry, -1.

Comment: @IInspectable if you had actually bothered to read the whole post before downvoting it, you would have seen the link to `Microsoft PE and COFF Specification`, which is as much a documented contract as it can get, as well as instructions on how to find the exact address of PE header in any `.exe` file. If you have a more reliable source than Microsoft's official specification on Microsoft's own executable format, I would love to know what that is.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo: *"Check the first printable characters after the first occurrence of PE"* - That's blatantly wrong, no? The PE header can be **anywhere** in the file. And while the PE file format is documented, the `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` is not. Also, right on the first page of that so-called *"specification"* you'll find: *"This document is provided to aid in the development of tools and applications for Windows but **is not guaranteed to be a complete specification** in all respects. Microsoft reserves the right to alter this document without notice"*. The down-vote is well deserved, sorry.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on an exe created with C++ native code, visual studio 2013.  Using this technique one can conclude it's 32bit, but in fact it's 64-bit, and can be verified by dumpbin and sigcheck

Comment: @zumalifeguard can I have a look at that exe?

Comment: Sure Alexander.   Give me your e-mail address and I'll send it to you.  if you can, you can DM me your e-mail address on Twitter.

Comment: @zumalifeguard I can't seem to contact you on Twitter, and I'm not really a fan of idea to giving my email to people on the Internet (no offence). Could you maybe upload it on some kind of file sharing service, like Google Drive, or something? Thanks.

Comment: @zumalifeguard Thanks for sending me the .exe. I checked it using my technique and it shows `PE  d†`, which is 64-bit, which is exactly what my post says it is. I'm not sure why you thought that my posts suggests it's a 32-bit one.

Comment: First file I check, there's no "PE", only "MZ" so I guess this solution is not foolproof

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper try running an actual search with your editor.

Comment: Yeah I tried with Notepad++ ;) Found another way that works 100% anyways, so it's all good thanks!

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper I'd like to study that .exe so that I could make my answer more accurate, if you don't mind and have the time to upload it somewhere, of course. I do have to say, though, that I have yet to see a single .exe that my answer didn't work for (so far it was only people misinterpreting the results) so excuse me if I am a bit skeptical. Anyway, my goal is provide accurate information, so I'd appreciate it if you could help me get my hands on that .exe :)

Comment: For files that start with "MZ", you need to look a bit further. I found PE..L at offset 0x110, just after "RichMQ_........".

Comment: Opened with XVI32 hex editor without any problems. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the technique!  It works for me, but note that this statement in your answer "the offset of PE Signature is located at offset 0x3C" is not always correct.  Doxygen 32-bit EXE for example has PE header @ 0x108.  In case anyone's interested this command will help apply this technique on linux:  hexdump -C <file> | grep 'PE' | head -n 5 (gives first 5 matches of 'PE' in the file)

Comment: @codesniffer you are correct, however it says in the answer that "the **offset** of PE signature is located at offset 0x3C", not the signature itself.

Comment: @codesniffer: Nice. If you're unlucky, `PE` might be at the end of a line, though, right? I used `strings -n1 <file> | head`.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo: I don't understand your comment. I meant that `PE` might be at the end of line in `hexdump`. For what it's worth, the command above with `strings` worked fine, and output `MZP
@
 
!
L
!
This program must be run under Win32
$7
PE
L
`.

Comment: @EricDuminil ah, nvm, I misunderstood yours :P

Comment: @AlexanderRevo - Thanks for the clarrification that 0x3C specifies the offset to the PE Signature.

@EricDuminil - Yes that's certainly possible.  Could augment the command to additionally include the next line after each line with 'PE' from hexdump:  `hexdump -C <file> | grep -A 1 'PE' | head -n 15` (gives first 5 matches of 'PE' in the file, each followed by next 16 bytes)

Comment: Here's an enhanced version of the linux script to get the machine type using the specific offset from 0x3C:
`QUERYFILE="MyWindowsExe.exe" ; hexdump -C -s $(hexdump -s 0x3C -n 4 -v -e '1/1 "%02x"'  "$QUERYFILE" | sed -e 's/\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/0x\4\3\2\1/') -n 6 "$QUERYFILE"` and here's a sample output for a 64-bit file (doxygen.exe):
`00000118  50 45 00 00 64 86                                 |PE..d.|`

Comment: And here's an even more enhanced version which parses the 32-bit & 64-bit type values and outputs "64-bit" or "32-bit" (or if neither is found then it outputs "ERROR:  Failed to identify Windows PE machine type."): `QUERYFILE="MyWindowsExe.exe"  ; PESIG=$(hexdump -C -s $(hexdump -s 0x3C -n 4 -v -e '1/1 "%02x"'  "$QUERYFILE" | sed -e 's/\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/0x\4\3\2\1/') -n 6 "$QUERYFILE") ; echo "$PESIG" | grep ' 64 86' 2>/dev/null && echo "64-bit" || ( echo "$PESIG" | grep ' 4c 01' 2>/dev/null && echo "32-bit" || echo "ERROR:  Failed to identify Windows PE machine type." )`

Comment: This method does not always work coorectly, C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe shows PE L but is actually 64 bit on Windows.

Comment: @Shayan I have the correct 64-bit header in notepad.exe on my Windows 10 20H2. Make sure you're looking at the very first occurrence of PE in the file, if in doubt you can check with a hex-editor (see "Additional info").

Comment: @AlexanderRevo Hello again! So, I'm on Windows 10 ver1803, idk why the very first PE for me is L. Please have a look at this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/uar1KVs.png I loaded it in Notepad++. But as you mentioned, Hex Editor, shows PE��d†� which means 64 bit, so idk why Notepad++ doesn't work well here. Thanks a lot

Comment: When I `type` & `fc /b` notepad.exe on Win 10, I get `MZÉ` & `4D 5A 90` headers: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NOTEPAD.EXE

Comment: I like this answer because notepad.exe is so super simple; I was able to find PE d etc... so I now know that I had a 64 bit binary. I compiled this via msys2 actually. I was surprised to see the .exe can be relocated. Perhaps it could even be used to compile a huge .exe containing ALL THE THINGS! :D

Comment: What about for ARM executables?

Answer (score 171):

The SDK tool `dumpbin.exe` with the `/headers` option includes this information, compare these two (I've added bold for the key information)

```
PS [64] E:\ #4> dumpbin /headers C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               6 number of sections
        4CE798E5 time date stamp Sat Nov 20 09:46:13 2010
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
              22 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
[...]
```

and

```
PS [64] E:\ #5> dumpbin /headers C:\Windows\syswow64\cmd.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Windows\syswow64\cmd.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               4 number of sections
        4CE78E2B time date stamp Sat Nov 20 09:00:27 2010
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
             102 characteristics
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine
[...]
```

Comment: You could also see (IA64) for a 64bit Itanium exe.

Comment: as i read elsewhere on superuser, using `dumpbin /headers | findstr "machine"` greatly simplifies the presentation of what the QA is looking for...

Comment: Dumpbin.exe is located here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin`

Comment: @David: not necessarily (different version of VS, not using the default install location, using version from the Windows SDK): that is why I didn't specify.

Comment: It's easiest to use dumpbin if you launch it from the visual studio command-line: http://stackoverflow.com/a/477389/1390430

Comment: It is kinda diffiicult for ppl who dont have visual studio installed.

Comment: system**32** \cmd.exe shows x64 and syswow**64** \cmd.exe shows x86.. 
So to confirm.. 8664 Machine is 64 bit. Right ?

Comment: A way to find the location of dumpbin: `C:\>dir /s/b dumpbin.exe`

Answer (score 79):

If you don't have or want the whole Windows SDK or Visual Studio, you can use [`sigcheck.exe` from SysInternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck):

```
sigcheck.exe C:\Windows\Notepad.exe
```

Output:

```
Sigcheck v2.1 - File version and signature viewer
Copyright (C) 2004-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

c:\windows\notepad.exe:
    Verified:       Signed
    Signing date:   8:59 AM 8/22/2013
    Publisher:      Microsoft Windows
    Description:    Notepad
    Product:        Microsoft« Windows« Operating System
    Prod version:   6.3.9600.16384
    File version:   6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
    MachineType:    64-bit
```

Comment: Seems to be not always accurate: Try to use it with LinqPad.exe (AnyCPU-64bit version) and Sigcheck will tell you it's "32 bit" ...

Comment: @Matt interesting. LinqPad sounds like a .net app; I wonder if sigcheck only works correctly on native executables (for this purpose).

Comment: Yes, it is a .NET app. In .NET, if it isn't precompiled, you can either target "x86" or "AnyCPU". "x86" will always run as 32 bit, but AnyCPU will run as 64bit on a 64 bit system, but as 32 bit on a 32 bit system. SigCheck should consider this and show at least ".NET 32 bit or 64 bit (AnyCPU)". ILSpy for example  says in this case "Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)" - but ILSpy will not work for non-.NET EXE's.

Comment: @Matt that makes a lot of sense then; the native "stub" is probably 32 bit and then it initiates the 64 bit runtime where appropriate? Good find.

Comment: That might be the case, like the old "MZ" header which just is there for non-Windows ("DOS") OS saying "This application requires Microsoft Windows" ... ;-)

Comment: @Matt yesss it was actually a complete executable, and in visual studio you could set what you wanted it to be. You could literally support both DOS and Windows versions of the app in a single file, or the "DOS version" could do something completely different. I wrote an application for Windows, and then the DOS exe inside was its own menu system offering utilities to do things you had to do while Windows wasn't running (change start menu caption, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, the good old times, where you had a DOS debugger in the shell and could disassemble the code (which just contained one single DOS call printing this message)... and replace the text by "The answer is 42." :-D

Comment: Does this work for ARM executables?

Comment: @AaronFranke I'm afraid I don't know..

Comment: This should be the first answer

Answer (score 76):

I can confirm that the `file` utility (e.g. from cygwin) will distinguish between 32- and 64-bit executables. They appear as follows:

```
32.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
64.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

As you can see, it's very obvious which is which. Additionally it distinguishes between console and GUI executables, also obvious which is which.

Comment: This solution is pretty commonly available for any developers who have installed msysgit.

Comment: Why executable files in windows have `MZ` instead of `PE`?

Comment: Worth noting that GNU utilities can be obtained as individual binaries if you otherwise don't need Cygwin. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

Comment: We can use the `file` command using Git Bash utility also. Which would be installed by many these days along with GIT installation

Comment: @BattleTested_закалённыйвбою it's not instead: each PE file starts with an MZ stub that usually prints "This program cannot be run in DOS mode" when run in DOS.

Comment: `file` has a long history and is available to a wide variety of Linux/UNIX variants. I mainly use it to check if a bundled binary in a _buggy_ container image has a wrong architecture, where build hosts, container images/layers or build caches of different architectures are involved in a build process (e.g. amd64 image on aarch64 build host).

Answer (score 53):

Many people have the excellent [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) installed, and have added the 7-Zip folder to their `PATH`. 7-zip understands file formats other than ZIP and RAR, such as MSI files and PE executables. Simply use the command line `7z.exe` on the PE file (Exe or DLL) in question:

```
7z l some.exe | more
7z l some.exe | findstr CPU
```

Output will include lines as follows, with the `CPU` line reading either `x86` or `x64`, which is what is being asked here:

```
Path = C:\Extra\AV\neroAacEnc.exe
Type = PE
CPU = x86
Characteristics = Executable 32-bit

Path = C:\Extra\AV\LAME\lame_enc.dll
Type = PE
CPU = x86
Characteristics = Executable DLL 32-bit

Path = C:\Extra\AV\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe
Type = PE
CPU = x64
64-bit = +
Characteristics = Executable LargeAddress NoRelocs NoLineNums NoLocalSyms NoDebugInfo

Path = C:\Extra\AV\FFmpeg\bin\avcodec-56.dll
Type = PE
CPU = x64
64-bit = +
Characteristics = Executable DLL LargeAddress NoLineNums NoLocalSyms NoDebugInfo
```

Comment: wow I've never known that 7z can do this. Probably it contains a `file` implementation inside?

Comment: worked on linux!!!

Comment: Interesting - but does not always work for me: the 64bit executable from https://www.rapidee.com/en/about "cannot be opened as an archive".

Comment: While it works on “itself” (`7z l 7z.exe`), it doesn't work on, for example, `iconv.exe` as included in Strawberry Perl or Git for Windows. I checked with 7-zip 23.01 (x64).

Comment: @Wolf - Works for me on `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\iconv.exe` using `7-Zip 22.01 ZS v1.5.5 R3 (x64)` ([Zstd/Brotli extended version by McMilk](https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip-zstd/releases)): `Path = C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\iconv.exe ; Type = PE ; Physical Size = 36115 ; CPU = x64 ; … ; Checksum = 57508 …` • Works identically using older `7-Zip 19.00 (x64) … 2019-02-21` on my computer (Windows 22H2 [Version 10.0.19045.3693]).

Comment: @Lumi I can confirm this on my machine regarding the `iconv.exe` shipped with Git. For finding the difference between several `iconv.exe` binaries, I finally used the [`file`](https://superuser.com/a/702885/391675) command that comes with git bash.

Answer (score 34):

A simple method is to run it (assuming you trust it) and take a look at the process tab in task manager. 32bit processes will show "* 32" at the end of the process name. If it's not something your willing to run on your computer you can try [EXE Explorer](http://www.mitec.cz/exe.html). It will show a whole bunch of info on executables including if it's 32 or 64bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires you to run the executable.  Perhaps you need to check the architecture of the program as a troubleshooting method on why it is not running.

Comment: How do **you** run a DLL?

Comment: @user34660 [RUNDLL32.EXE <dllname>,<entrypoint>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044435/1105214)

Comment: @samusarin that should be in the post.

Comment: @user34660 You're technically correct, a DLL doesn't have a **`main`** entry point and so will not execute as a stand alone process. There is an initialization function called when it is loaded but that isn't "main".

Comment: You can also see if a program is 64bit or 32 bit on Task Manager's Details tab, just have to enable the "Platorm" column by right clicking on one of the columns and click Select Columns

Answer (score 26):

Here's a Powershell solution, no external dependencies or anything. Open Powershell, paste the function in there (hit Enter twice so that you return to the prompt), then use it as in my examples below the function:

```
function Test-is64Bit {
    param($FilePath=“$env:windir\notepad.exe”)

    [int32]$MACHINE_OFFSET = 4
    [int32]$PE_POINTER_OFFSET = 60

    [byte[]]$data = New-Object -TypeName System.Byte[] -ArgumentList 4096
    $stream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList ($FilePath, 'Open', 'Read')
    $stream.Read($data, 0, 4096) | Out-Null

    [int32]$PE_HEADER_ADDR = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($data, $PE_POINTER_OFFSET)
    [int32]$machineUint = [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt16($data, $PE_HEADER_ADDR + $MACHINE_OFFSET)
    $stream.Close()

    $result = "" | select FilePath, FileType, Is64Bit
    $result.FilePath = $FilePath
    $result.Is64Bit = $false

    switch ($machineUint) 
    {
        0      { $result.FileType = 'Native' }
        0x014c { $result.FileType = 'x86' }
        0x0200 { $result.FileType = 'Itanium' }
        0x8664 { $result.FileType = 'x64'; $result.is64Bit = $true; }
    }

    $result
}
```

Here's example output:

```
D:\> Test-is64bit

FilePath               FileType Is64Bit
--------               -------- -------
C:\Windows\notepad.exe x64         True


D:\> Test-is64bit 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'

FilePath                                           FileType Is64Bit
--------                                           -------- -------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe x86        False
```

Comment: Slickness. The above script seems to leave a reference to the file open.  Couldn't build until I first closed powershell (ran script to interrogate DLL in \bin).

Comment: Very cool. +1. Itanium is definitely 64bit though :)

Comment: @samusarin: maybe add `$stream.dispose();` after the close? Should release file handles. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999858/how-bad-is-it-to-not-dispose-in-powershell )

Comment: a more complete version can be found in [Check if exe is 64-bit](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11373/2563)

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was scrolling down looking for.  No need to link to an sdk or put rando binaries in my repo to run these checks during CI

Comment: if  you're curious about the `$result = "" | select FilePath, FileType, Is64Bit` section, that's how you could create objects before WinPs 4 and `[pscustomobject]` -- meaning it's from before 2012

Answer (score 23):

The 64-bit version of [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can tell you. Simply run the executable and open the process's properties window. On the main tab there's an entry which says "Image:32 Bit" or "Image:64 Bit".

[image]

Comment: `Simply run the executable` And what if you don’t want to *run* the program?

Comment: @Synetech The original question doesn't imply that's the case.

Comment: This is the easiest method for me I think, unless the executable exits too fast.

Comment: How do **you** run a DLL?

Comment: Run it with `rundll32.exe file.dll,DllEntry`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, notably for the image and for marking the region of interest, and +1. I am using Process Explorer all the time anyway, but somehow always missed that information in the properties dialog box. Incredible ...

Answer (score 22):

**Most simple way** (when the data aren't confidential)

I find that [Virustotal](http://www.virustotal.com) `File detail` is the simplest way to find out if a binary is 32 bit or 64 bit.

The `Additional information` option provides in addition much helpful informations about the file.

[image: Virustotal analysis]

---

[image: [Virustotal TrID]

Answer (score 16):

The method of running an executable & then checking in process explorer or similar tool, has some obvious drawbacks:

1. We have to execute the process.
2. For the short lived processes (like echo hello world types.), process explorer might not even register that a new process has started.

Dumpbin.exe method can solve the purpose probably.

Another alternative would be to use cygwin's **file** command. However, I have not tested it on windows. It works well on Linuxes.

```
Usage: file program_under_test.exe
```

EDIT: Just tested file.exe on window. works fine. :)

Comment: This adds nothing that wasn't said by Dracs or Richard.  This still requires running the program which the author wanted to avoid.

Comment: Just wanted to say, that there are some situations, where Dracs's method will not be much helpful.

Comment: >>This still requires running the program which the author wanted to avoid:

No.. we run it like: file.exe program_under_test.exe

Comment: And those who wish to avoid installing the whole `cygwin` package can grab the [gnuwin32 `file` package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).

Comment: I just ran the cygwin "file" command and it says nothing about 32 versus 64 bits:

  `MS-DOS executable PE  for MS Windows (console), Mono/.Net assembly`

Comment: Looks like your 'file' binary itself is 32 bit. Hence it will not be able to detect 32 vs 64 bit. You need 64 bit version of file utility. Check here: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2013-07/msg00030.html

Comment: @anishsane Completely wrong. `file` simply reads data from the disk in binary format and checks for any magic numbers identifying them, comparing against a database. Windows' 32-bit programs come up as PE32, and both 64-bit and .NET programs come up as PE32+. The bitness of `file` itself makes absolutely zero difference - both 32-bit and 64-bit applications can read data from the disk, which is all it needs.

Comment: @MarcH No, it told you it's a .NET assembly, which doesn't have bit-ness. It's neither win32 nor win64, it's .NET.

Comment: @clacke interesting thanks. Now here is something even more interesting: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Syncplicity/Syncplicity.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
   This one runs without any *32 in task manager.

Comment: ... and sigcheck.exe reports Syncplicity.exe as 32 bits.

Comment: @MarcH Ha! That *is* interesting. I'm guessing that means the .NET runtime stub is 32-bit. So it runs a 32-bit process for a fraction of a second, but all that process does is start the .NET runtime, which creates a native 64-bit process.

Comment: Makes me think that PE32+ .NET files make no sense, they should all be PE32 to make sure they run on both platforms. But maybe the stub code never runs -- it's possible that Windows discovers that it's a .NET binary and just runs .NET directly. Would be great to hear a comment from someone who actually knows. :-)

Comment: It seems that Windows 2000 ran the stub to initiate the .NET runtime, but XP and later detects a .NET binary and runs .NET itself. It doesn't create a new process though, it starts .NET in the existing process and if it's a PE32 on a 64-bit system, it converts it in-memory to PE32+ before proceeding. https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/14d2158d-9df7-448b-a2ac-adfcac2be6cb/how-does-the-clr-get-loaded

Answer (score 13):

Even an executable marked as 32-bit can run as 64-bit if, for example, it's a .NET executable that can run as 32- or 64-bit. For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782191/how-do-i-determine-if-a-net-application-is-32-or-64-bit, which has an answer that says that the CORFLAGS utility can be used to determine how a .NET application will run.

**CORFLAGS.EXE output**

For 32-bit executable:

```
Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x3
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 1
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 0
```

For 64-bit executable:

```
Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32+
CorFlags  : 0x1
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 0
```

For executable that can run as 32- or 64-bit and will run as 64-bit when possible:

```
Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x1
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 0
```

For executable that can run as 32- or 64-bit, but will run as 32-bit unless loaded into a 64-bit process:

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x20003
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 1
Signed    : 0
```

Comment: Cool command, but it won't work for native (non-managed) executables / dlls. (`corflags : error CF008 : The specified file does not have a valid managed header`)

Comment: @TomaszGandor Yes, the context of this answer was managed code only. Unmanaged code is answered by the other answers. As far as I know, only managed code can switch between executing as both 32- and 64-bit.

Comment: I personally would use other solutions, but summarizing that matter and showing all possible cases deserved an upvote.

Answer (score 11):

If you are on Windows 7, on a Windows Explorer, right click on the executable and select Properties.
At the properties window select the Compatibility tab.
If under the Compatibility Mode section you see Windows XP, this is a 32 bit executable.
If you see Windows Vista, it is 64 bit.

Comment: -1 not true at all. Various 32 and 64 bit binaries are all shown an Compatibility Mode of `Windows 8`

Comment: @Peter I've tried quite a few on Windows 7 and it always worked for me. Could you give an example of a binary where the default compatibility mode is Windows 8? Also what Windows are you on? Thanks.

Comment: I'm on Server 2012 R2 and tried a few random binaries. Some 32bit ones show as `Windows XP SP2` but others show as `Vista` or `Windows 8`. So this method is not correct.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf their language is a bit off but what he meant is when you open up the compatibility drop-down, if XP is an option at all it is 32bit. Otherwise if the only options you have are Vista-onwards, it's x64

Comment: Nice trick! As stated above, open the drop-down to see all the options. If xp is there at all = 32bit

Answer (score 11):

My two cents will be just download [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and check what for architecture has been used in one of the executable file.

## How to use it:

Just simply download app, start it up, click on open icon → find an *.exe file → select and on the bottom after reflection scan is done you see a grid with data where one column has "architecture" details in it (x86, x64)

Open executable and see the build architecture

[image: dependency walker screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

## How to add 32/64 bit test to your context menu

Create a text file named **exetest.reg** and containing this code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; What will appear in the contextual menu when right-clicking on a .exe file
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\command32_64]
@="32/64 bit test"

; What to do with it
; here, %1 is the file given as argument of the script
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\command32_64\command]
@="\"c:\\temp\\x86TestStart.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Create a text file named `x86TestStart.bat` containing just this line of code and save it in C:\temp:

```
c:\temp\x86or64.vbs %1
```

Create a text file named `x86or64.vbs` containing this code and save it in C:\temp:

```vbs
rem Reading binary file in VBScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249440/modify-first-two-bytes-of-a-file-using-vbscript
rem Info on executables: https://dmoj.ca/problem/exe

rem x86/64 signature is located dinamycally; its position is addressed
rem from bytes in 0x3C-0x3D position.

rem Possible signatures;
rem "PE..L" (hex code: 50.45.00.00.4C) = 32 bit
rem "PE..d†" (hex code: 50.45.00.00.64.86) = 64 bit

' ------------------------------------
' Source code by Jumpkack 2015
' ------------------------------------

' Read all arguments from command line:
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

' Store first argument (full path to file)
FileName = args(0)

' Find address of executable signature:
FirstChars = readBinary(FileName)
FirstChars = FirstChars
Addr1 = asc(mid(FirstChars,61,1))
Addr2 = asc(mid(FirstChars,62,1))
AddrFinal = Addr2*256 + Addr1 + 1

' Check signature:
if ucase(hex(asc(mid(FirstChars,AddrFinal+4,2)))) = "4C" then Wscript.Echo Filename & " is a 32 bit executable."
if ucase(hex(asc(mid(FirstChars,AddrFinal+4,2)))) = "64" then Wscript.Echo Filename & " is a 64 bit executable."


Function readBinary(path)
    Dim a, fso, file, i, ts
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = fso.getFile(path)
    If isNull(file) Then
        wscript.echo "File not found: " & path
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set ts = file.OpenAsTextStream()
    'a = makeArray(file.size)
    a=""
    i = 0
    While (Not ts.atEndOfStream) and (i<60000)
       'a(i) = ts.read(1)
       a = a + ts.read(1)
       i = i + 1
    Wend
    ts.close
    readBinary = a
 End Function
```

Double click on exetest.reg file:  a new key will be added in the windows registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\command32_64\command]
```

It will appear as "**32/64 bit test**" in context menu upon right clicking on an executable  file.

Clicking the item will result in starting batch file `c:\\temp\\x86TestStart.bat\`, which starts VBscript file `x86or64.vbs` , which reads exe signature and shows result.

If you cannot or don't want to tamper with registry, just copy the .vbs file in QuickLaunch bar, and drag executable over it.

Comment: I find this solution to take too much effort, and I therefore won't use it. However, putting it together really deserved my upvote. Well done ...

Comment: The line `FirstChars = FirstChars` is pointless and can be deleted. Not sure if that was meant to be something different?

Comment: I wanted to thank you for posting this answer. It inspired me to write a more-generic function that I posted to [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/franklesniak/VBScript_Resources) in a file called `GetExecutableProcessorArchitectureFromFile.vbs`. It reads an exe's PE header, gets the machine type, and returns the processor architecture (i.e., if the executable was running and accessed the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable, the contents of that variable), in string format.

Answer (score 7):

Yet, [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)'s `file` command works greatly.

`file /mnt/c/p/bin/rg.exe` would output:

```
/mnt/c/p/bin/rg.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

`file /mnt/c/p/bin/u.exe` would output:

```
/mnt/c/p/bin/u.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows, UPX compressed
```

Comment: That's nice! You could even call `wsl file rg.exe` from the directory where rg.exe is located.

Answer (score 6):

you can also use the `file` tool from within the [msys2 bundle of mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/msys2). It works like the unix command. Similar works the `file` tool from [GNUwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).

Answer (score 6):

The platform column in the task manager of windows 10

Windows 7 doesn't have a platform column.  So Windows 7 task manager won't show it.

In windows 10 choosing columns is not under 'view' anymore. In Windows 10, when in the details tab,  you right click column header then 'select columns'. Then check the box for 'platform'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This requires running the application, which might be undesirable. Also, you "cannot" run a DLL.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand fair point in a sense, though he didn't mention a dll, he just said application.. also, and the DLL will match the EXE in 'bitness'

Answer (score 4):

The Simplest Solution is that the 32-bit version has windows XP listed on the compatibility tab of the properties ( tested on Windows 7 & 10 ) of the executable file.

Firefox 32 Bit:

[image]

Firefox 64 Bit:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen this mentioned. There is a PE viewer program called CFF Explorer by [NTCore](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php), which can provide you this information. It can be downloaded and run as portable, but you can install it as well, if you wish.

Right click on the binary (`.exe`, `.dll` etc.) and select "Open with CFF Explorer". Go to Nt Headers -> File Header -> On the "Characteristics" field click "Click here"

If it's a 32bit program, the checkbox "32 bit word machine" will be ticked. For instance, i have installed the 32bit version of Notepad++ as you can see in the image below. Otherwise, it's 64bit.

[image]

Comment: There is a quicker way with CFF explorer: immediately when loading a file, under "file type" you have "Portable Executable 64" or "Portable Executable 32"

Answer (score 2):

my two cents:
as a C++ developer, dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is very informative, not only displays 64/32 bits, but also every Dll involved:
[image]

You can see 64 on left of every file name...

Comment: Screenshot does not display the answer - 32bit vs 64bit info...

Comment: @TomEus there's "64" in the screenshot, but not in the file name but inside the file logo (on the right side)

Answer (score 2):

My simple version in Powershell, seems to be 100% reliable from my tests.

```
Clear-Host
$Check32Bit = $null
$Check64Bit = $null

$File = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"

$ExeData = get-content $File -totalcount 50

$Check32Bit = $ExeData | select-string -Pattern "PE..L" -Quiet
$Check64Bit = $ExeData | select-string -Pattern "PE..d†" -Quiet

if ($Check32Bit) {
"File is 32bit (x86)"
}
elseif ($Check64Bit) {
"File is 64bit (x64)"
}
else {
"Couldn't identify if the file is 32bit or 64bit"
}
```

Comment: Using Powershell 7.4.1, this solution does not work.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a comment by **@user1055604**, the easiest out-of-the-box way of doing this on Windows 10 is:

```
dumpbin /headers yourfile.lib | findstr "machine"
```

This one-liner will produce an intuitive result as an output. For example, on a 64-bit library I just tested, it printed the following:

**8664 machine (x64)**

Comment: Dumpbin is not part of a default Windows install. It comes with the Common Tools for Visual C++. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38616596/102351

Answer (score 1):

- run the application
- open Task Manager
- right click and create dump file
- note down path
- go to path and open `.DMP` dump in Visual Studio
- there you get all the details
- check process architecture:

Comment: I feel obligated to underscore the fact that this answer requires running the application. Previous commenters suggested that this might be undesirable. Also, Visual Studio will not automatically be available on all Windows platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use corflags from VS command prompt to change machine type

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool

Change Machine Type:

```
corflags d:\abc.exe /32BITREQ-
```

Verify using corflags:

```
corflags d:\abc.exe
```

`32BITREQ : 0 ** 0` means 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

I know they are many answers here, but none of them are really portable and require some kind of tool to use. I wanted to solve this in a programmatic way for all platforms. This will work on anything with a C compiler.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>      // std::fstream
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char Header      [0x200];
char Elf32Magic  [20] = "\x7f\x45\x4c\x46\01";  //7F 45 4C 46  01 // ELF32 
char Elf64Magic  [20] = "\x7f\x45\x4c\x46\02";  //7F 45 4C 46  02 // ELF64
char Win32Magic  [20] = "\x50\x45\x00\x00\x4C\x01";// PE32
char Win64Magic  [20] = "\x50\x45\x00\x00\x64\x86";// PE64

char PeHeader[20] = {};
void CheckWinHeader(){
  int k = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 0x200; i++)
  {
   if(Header[i] == 0x50 && Header[i+1] == 0x45) // PE     
     {

      for(int j = i; j < i + 6; j++)
      {
        PeHeader[k] = Header[j];
        k++;
       //printf("%hhx", Header[j]); 
      }
     }
  }
}


int main(){
  std::fstream fs; 
  fs.open ("/home/PATH/TO/YOUR/BINARY", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
  fs.read( Header , 0x200);
 
  if(memcmp ( Header, Elf32Magic, 5 ) == 0 ){
    printf("ELF 32 Match Found ! \n");
  }
  if(memcmp ( Header, Elf64Magic, 5 ) == 0 ){
    printf("Elf 64 Match Found ! \n");
  }

  CheckWinHeader();

  if(memcmp ( &PeHeader, Win32Magic, 6 ) == 0 ){
    printf("Win 32 Match Found ! \n");
  }

  if(memcmp ( &PeHeader, Win64Magic, 6 ) == 0 ){
    printf("Win 64 Match Found ! \n");
  }

 fs.close();
 return 0;
}
```

compile by using any compiler. I used g++.

```
g++ Bincheck.cpp -o bincheck
./bincheck
```

Comment: There's no C compiler by default in Windows so this isn't quite useful. If you have gcc then you'll have `file` command and if you have MSVC there's `dumpbin` available so there's no need to compiler such a program. OTOH there's notepad and powershell on Windows so you can check the binary type using either way easily without any 3rd party tools

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scan a folder structure for 32/64 bit DLL's or executables, you can also try a free tool called ScanFor64bit, found at: https://canservices.nl/download-tools
ScanFor64bit allows you to enter a drive-letter or directory-path and one or more filemasks to scan for 32 or 64 bitness.
The result is a list sorted by 32bit files first and 64bit second.
I have used it a lot to check computers with Java to make sure the 64 bit version is used.

[Output example of ScanFor64bit:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cETgk.png)

Answer (score 1):

Something different from all the excellent answers above, but use PowerShell to search for the telltale "This program must be run under Win32"?

```
PS C:\Program Files\Snap Inc> ls -R . -filter *.exe | % { $file = $_; Select-String -Path $_ -Encoding 'oem' -Pattern 'under Win32' -SimpleMatch -Quiet } | % { Write-Output "$file is Win32: $_" }

Snap Camera.exe is Win32: False
unins000.exe is Win32: True
installer.exe is Win32: False
```

This also matches the results for the `PE L` and `PE d†` trick.

Answer (score 0):

Many excellent answers already, some claiming "most simple", but the **absolute simplest** way is inspecting the folder path.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\`  is intended for 32-bit stuff.

See e.g. [this Microsoft post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220329-00/?p=106404):

*On Windows editions that support x86 emulation, there are two directories for program files. The C:\Program Files directory is for programs in the native system bitness, and the the C:\Program Files (x86) directory is for programs that run under the x86-32 emulator. But why are they separate directories? Why can’t we combine them? ...*

Of course, there is no 101% guarantee that nobody ever puts any 64-bit stuff in the 32-bit folder, but as a first quick check it is useful to look at X86 in the folder name.

Comment: (downvoter: care to explain?)

Comment: because it's absolutely not true. There are lots of apps that have some 64-bit tool in `C:\Program Files (x86)`, and some apps even install the 64-bit version there. I can install any app to any folder I want. Besides, that path isn't fixed and can be changed

Comment: One example is the old Visual Studio. Being an IDE obviously it must have some 64-bit tool for compiling/debugging 64-bit apps, but most of the binaries are 32-bit and the entire package is 32-bit

Comment: @phuclv My method is perhaps not 100% _reliable_, but to say that my answer is _absolutely not true_ might be exaggerated. To fix a problem, a simple method is useful for a first try, and your downvote should mean "the answer is NOT useful".

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer: [How to check if a binary is 32 or 64 bit on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows/889267#889267)

- Language: VBS
- OS: Windows XP+

Implementation: https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/vbs/read_pe_header_bitness.vbs

```vb
''' Read a binary file PE header bitness.

''' USAGE:
'''   read_pe_header_bitness.vbs <FilePath>

''' DESCRIPTION:
'''   <FilePath>
'''     Path to binary file to read.

' Check if a binary (EXE or DLL) is 32 bit (x86) or 64 bit (x64)

Sub PrintOrEchoLine(str)
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.stdout.WriteLine str
  If err = &h80070006& Then
    WScript.Echo str
  End If
  On Error Goto 0
End Sub

Sub PrintOrEchoErrorLine(str)
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.stderr.WriteLine str
  If err = &h80070006& Then
    WScript.Echo str
  End If
  On Error Goto 0
End Sub

ReDim cmd_args(WScript.Arguments.Count - 1)

Dim objShell : Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim arg
Dim j : j = 0

For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1 : Do ' empty `Do-Loop` to emulate `Continue`
  arg = WScript.Arguments(i)

  ' read command line flags here...

  cmd_args(j) = arg

  j = j + 1
Loop While False : Next

ReDim Preserve cmd_args(j - 1)

' MsgBox Join(cmd_args, " ")

Dim cmd_args_ubound : cmd_args_ubound = UBound(cmd_args)

If cmd_args_ubound < 0 Then
  PrintOrEchoErrorLine WScript.ScriptName & ": error: <FilePath> argument is not defined."
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

Dim FilePath : FilePath = cmd_args(0)

Dim objFS : Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim FilePathAbs : FilePathAbs = objFS.GetAbsolutePathName(FilePath) ' CAUTION: can alter a path character case if path exists

' remove `\\?\` prefix
If Left(FilePathAbs, 4) = "\\?\" Then
  FilePathAbs = Mid(FilePathAbs, 5)
End If

' test on path existence including long path
Dim IsFileExist : IsFileExist = objFS.FileExists("\\?\" & FilePathAbs)
If Not IsFileExist Then
  PrintOrEchoErrorLine _
    WScript.ScriptName & ": error: file does not exist:" & vbCrLf & _
    WScript.ScriptName & ": info: FilePath=`" & FilePathAbs & "`"
  WScript.Quit 2
End If

Dim FilePathToOpen

' test on long path existence
If objFS.FileExists(FilePathAbs) Then
  ' is not long path
  FilePathToOpen = FilePathAbs
Else
  ' translate into short path

  ' WORKAROUND:
  '   We use `\\?\` to bypass `GetFile` error: `File not found`.
  Dim File_ : Set File_ = objFS.GetFile("\\?\" & FilePathAbs)
  Dim FileShortPath : FileShortPath = File_.ShortPath
  If Left(FileShortPath, 4) = "\\?\" Then
    FileShortPath = Mid(FileShortPath, 5)
  End If

  FilePathToOpen = FileShortPath
End If

Dim BinaryStream : Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

BinaryStream.Type = 1
BinaryStream.Open

BinaryStream.LoadFromFile FilePathToOpen

Function ByteToHex(byte_)
  Dim str : str = Hex(byte_)
  If Len(str) = 1 Then
    str = "0" & str
  End If
  ByteToHex = str
End Function

Dim PeSignature : PeSignature = BinaryStream.Read(3)

Dim ByteCode
Dim PeHexStr

For i = 0 to UBound(PeSignature)
  ByteCode = Ascb(Midb(PeSignature, i + 1, 1))
  PeHexStr = PeHexStr & ByteToHex(ByteCode)
Next

rem compare on `MZђ` sequence
If PeHexStr <> "4D5A90" Then
  PrintOrEchoErrorLine _
    WScript.ScriptName & ": error: file has no PE header:" & vbCrLf & _
    WScript.ScriptName & ": info: FilePath=`" & FilePath & "`"
  WScript.Quit 3
End If

BinaryStream.Position = &H3C
Dim PositionSignature : PositionSignature = BinaryStream.Read(4)

Dim PositionHexStr

For i = 0 to UBound(PositionSignature)
    ByteCode = Ascb(Midb(PositionSignature, i + 1, 1))
    PositionHexStr = ByteToHex(ByteCode) & PositionHexStr
Next

BinaryStream.Position = CInt("&H" & PositionHexStr)

Dim BitnessSignature : BitnessSignature = BinaryStream.Read(6)

Dim BitnessHexStr

For i = 0 to UBound(BitnessSignature)
    ByteCode = Ascb(Midb(BitnessSignature, i + 1, 1))
    BitnessHexStr = BitnessHexStr & ByteToHex(ByteCode)
Next

BinaryStream.Close

If BitnessHexStr = "504500004C01" Then
  PrintOrEchoLine "32"
ElseIf BitnessHexStr = "504500006486" Then
  PrintOrEchoLine "64"
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution on the below link helpful.

https://www.appsloveworld.com/powershell/100/34/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-an-exe-is-32-or-64-bit

```
$machine_offset = 4
$pe_pointer_offset = 60
$machinetype = write-output native i386 itanium x64

$filepath = "$env:windir\notepad.exe"
$data = new-object system.byte[] 4096
$stream = new-object system.io.filestream -argumentlist $filepath,open,read
$stream.read($data,0,$pe_pointer_offset) | out-null
$pe_header_addr = [system.bitconverter]::toint32($data, 
$pe_pointer_offset)
$machineuint = [system.bitconverter]::touint16($data, $pe_header_addr + 
$machine_offset)
$machinetype[$machineuint]
```