# Every executable I read starts with header the MZ

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, 32-vs-64-bit, dosbox, 16-bit

I was initially trying to create a program to distinguish between DOS(16-bit) and Windows(32/64-bit) executables.

I read in some other answer that a executable can be classified based on their first two bytes. (MZ/...)

But when I manually went and compared a few executables (both 16 and (32/64 bit)), I found that they all started with MZ..

Is there any reason for it or am I doing something wrong?

The 16-bit executables were written by me in assembly->compiled using TASM and the 32/64 bit executables were from the system files of my computer `C:\Windows\System32`

Is there any other more accurate way to distinguish an executable?

Comment: MZ is a common start byte for any executable I have opened with a HEX Editor. I don't think you can determine from the first bytes whether 32-bit or 64-bit

Comment: http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=8&part=1 might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I found that they all started with `MZ`

`MZ` is indeed the characteristic signature of a `.exe` file:

> The DOS MZ executable format is the executable file format used for .EXE files in DOS.
>
> The file can be identified by the ASCII string "MZ" (hexadecimal: 4D 5A) at the beginning of the file (the "magic number"). "MZ" are the initials of Mark Zbikowski, one of leading developers of MS-DOS.

Source [DOS MZ executable - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable)

This signature was later extended to its descendants (including NE and PE):

> The New Executable (abbreviated NE or NewEXE) is a 16-bit .exe file format, a successor to the DOS MZ executable format. It was used in Windows 1.0–3.x, multitasking MS-DOS 4.0,[1] OS/2 1.x, and the OS/2 subset of Windows NT up to version 5.0 (Windows 2000). A NE is also called a segmented executable

Source [New Executable - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Executable)

> The Portable Executable (PE) format is a file format for executables,
>   object code, DLLs and others used in 32-bit and 64-bit versions of
>   Windows operating systems. The PE format is a data structure that
>   encapsulates the information necessary for the Windows OS loader to
>   manage the wrapped executable code. This includes dynamic library
>   references for linking, API export and import tables, resource
>   management data and thread-local storage (TLS) data. On NT operating
>   systems, the PE format is used for EXE, DLL, SYS (device driver), and
>   other file types. The Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI)
>   specification states that PE is the standard executable format in EFI
>   environments.
>
> On Windows NT operating systems, PE currently supports the IA-32,
>   IA-64, x86, x86-64 (AMD64/Intel 64), ARM and ARM64 instruction set
>   architectures (ISAs). Prior to Windows 2000, Windows NT (and thus PE)
>   supported the MIPS, Alpha, and PowerPC ISAs. Because PE is used on
>   Windows CE, it continues to support several variants of the MIPS, ARM
>   (including Thumb), and SuperH ISAs.

Source [Portable Executable - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)

So `MZ` is used for 16, 32 and 64 bit `.exe` signatures and cannot be used to distinguish between 16 and 32/64 bit programs.

---

#### So How do I distinguish between 16 and 32/64 bit programs?

> Windows has extended the old DOS executable format multiple times, so
>   if you look at a 'modern' Windows executable, right near the beginning
>   there will be a MZ (or possibly ZM if the executable is for a system
>   that uses the opposite bit order). This designates the header for the
>   second DOS executable format, known simply as the MZ format.
>
> Beyond that, you'll see some apparent gibberish, followed by something
>   along the lines of 'This program can't be run in DOS mode.'. That
>   gibberish is actually a really simple DOS program that prints out a
>   message to tell the user that that program can't be run in DOS.
>
> After that, you have the header for the actual executable, which may
>   start with one of four pairs of letters, NE, LX, LE, or PE. If you
>   don't see one of these and the above mentioned message, it's a 16-bit
>   DOS application.

Source [How to check if a binary is 16 bit on Windows](https://superuser.com/a/1334151/337631), answer by [Austin Hemmelgarn](https://superuser.com/users/751187/austin-hemmelgarn)

You can also use the Unix `file` command (which is available in Cygwin and [windows-subsystem-for-linux](/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux):

Example:

> ```
> C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin>file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE"
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE; PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit
> ```
>
> I believe when it is a 16bit executable it says something to the sorts
>   of MS-DOS or Win 3.X executable.

Source [Solved: Tip or tool to distingush 16/32/64 bit .exe files? | Tech Support Guy](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-tip-or-tool-to-distingush-16-32-64-bit-exe-files.994510/)

The above link also includes source code (looks like C) which you can play with.

Comment: You can also look at the source code for `file` at https://github.com/file/file