# Is there a command line tool to check 32-bit or 64-bit of an exe?

Tags: windows, command-line, architecture

On Windows, like:

```
is64 abc.exe  
1
```

and

```
is32 def.exe  
1
```

While abc.exe is compiled 64-bit and def.exe is 32-bit on Windows.

Comment: Not that I know of but creating an utility that reads the PE header of a binary shouldn't be overwhelmingly difficult. Studying the PE format right now, will answer if I figure it out.

Comment: 'Kay, figured it out and answered with a package of command line tools doing what you asked. I think.

Comment: [How to check if a binary is 32 or 64 bit on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/358434/241386)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Is there a command line tool to check 32-bit or 64-bit of an exe?**

Yes

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>file file.exe
file.exe; PE32 executable for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit

c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>cd ..\..\evernote\evernote   
c:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote>file evernote.exe
evernote.exe; PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit

c:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote>cd c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer    
c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer>file iexplore.exe
iexplore.exe; PE32+ executable for MS Windows (GUI) Mono/.Net assembly
```

The PE32 format stands for Portable Executable 32-bit, while PE32+ is Portable Executable 64-bit format.

See http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

> **like:**
>
> is64 abc.exe
>   1

Not exactly like that.

You can use the `-b` option to exclude the filename from the output, then you just need some command-line kung fu to extract the first word (PE32 or PE32+) compare it with PE32+ and use that in your ìf` statement.

---

### Windows 10

On Windows 10, if you have the anniversary update, if you [enable the bash shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about), you can open a bash shell and use the `file` command like this

```
rgb@MYPCNAME:/mnt/c$ file install.exe
install.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

or

```
rgb@MYPCNAME:/mnt/c/Program Files/Internet Explorer$ file ieinstal.exe
ieinstal.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a pair of programs strictly doing what you asked for (With the addition of error messages on errors et cetera.)
(And actually, it's one program with a define that changes its behaviour to be perfectly accurate, but that doesn't matter.)

You can find them on my Dropbox, [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7995419/is3264.zip). Source code is included in the package but you can discard it if it's unneeded. It's basically only included in case you don't trust my binaries.

**Example of use**:

```
>is32 C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe
1

>is64 C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe
0
```

Basically, the program works by first memory-mapping the binary, then locating the PE header and finally simply comparing the Machine field to the value for whichever architecture you ask for. Essentially a very simple process.

Comment: While file is probably the better solution, the +1 is because this kind of help should be rewarded.

Answer (score 3):

```
$  file access-client-win32.exe 

access-client-win32.exe: PE32 executable for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit


$ file access-client-win64.exe

access-client-win64.exe: PE32+ executable for MS Windows (console) Mono/.Net assembly

win32.exe -> PE32

win64.exe -> PE32+
```

ps: PE -> Portable Executable

Comment: Remember to properly format your answer. Use a right angle bracket `>` before each line of a block quote, and indent code blocks with four spaces.