# DLL Add-in won't run in Excel 2010 64-bit

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, dll

I have a DLL add-in for Excel that adds an API for another program I have.  Add-in had an installer package and after install I can't find it in the Excel add-ins list.  I have a suspicion that it is a 32-bit addin that may be causing the problem.  Is there a way to check if the DLL is 32-bit?  Even if it is 32-bit should it cause a problem to run on 64-bit Excel?  Help!

Comment: Unless you are 100% sure the add-on is able to support a 64-bit installation of Excel 2010 I would just remove the add-on in question.  The alternative is to remove the 64-bit version of Excel 2010 and install the 32-bit version instead.

Comment: Does this add-in purport to work with Excel 2010 at all?

Comment: Yea i know it works for other people, though I've only asked one person what bit version and they were using 32

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to check if the DLL is 32-bit?

You can refer to the question, [How can I find out if a given program is 64 or 32 bit version?](https://superuser.com/questions/257046/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-given-program-is-64-or-32-bit-version), for that. That will work for DLLs and libraries, too.

> Even if it is 32-bit should it cause a problem to run on 64-bit Excel?

Yes. 32-bit programs cannot load a 64-bit library, and vise-versa. So if you have a 32-bit Add In that you need to use, then you need to install the 32-bit Excel.

Comment: How do I use it check the dll? Can't figure it out.

Comment: @riotburn - Follow the directions....The answer for the linked question explains how to use the tool.  Just do `file myfile.dll` instead of `file myfile.exe` just common sense.

Comment: doesn't work just get 'file' is not recognized as an internal or external command.  This is after  cd to the directory containing the dll and then typing file  my.dll

Comment: If the addin was explicitly compiled for use on 32-bit systems then your out of luck. Typically 32-bit software is fine running on 64-bit, but only if it was compiled as such.