# What are some nice command line ways to inspect DLL/EXE details?

Tags: windows, command-line

With most Windows executables (DLL, EXE...), version and other details can be viewed using "Details" tab in "Properties" (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

[image: Details of shell32.dll from Windows 7 amd64]

I wonder: is there also a command-line way to do this? I'm particularly interested for Product version, but also other things could be useful.

Following properties are desired, in order of precedence:

- accept exe/dll path as a parameter
- output to standard output (so you can process the rest via `|` pipe)
- available by default in all supported Windows (XP+)
- available by default in Windows Vista+
- available by default in Windows XP
- usable in commercial environment
- free license (GPL-like)
- portable (ie. standalone exe, maybe accompanied with DLL)

Comment: This has been already asked on Stack Overflow: [Command line tool to dump Windows DLL version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602802/command-line-tool-to-dump-windows-dll-version)

Answer (score 14):

In powershell, `get-command "full-path-to-executable" | format-list` would do the trick. Powershell is the new command-line
for Vista and later Windows, can be installed in XP.

Comment: I can't get your code to work...

Comment: I've got as far as `get-command "$args[0]" | format-list`, which i've saved as `aaa.ps1` and called as `powershell -File aaa.ps1 shell32.dll` but that does not print anything.

Comment: @soandos: it appears powershell v2 is required for get-command to work with arbitrary executables.

Comment: I have powershell v2

Comment: nice, I didn't knew that, it even return a little more information than the property window. The interesting info is encapsulated in the `FileInfoVersion` property of the `ApplicationInfo` object.

Comment: It still works in Powershell 7.4.1

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`sigcheck.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) portable tool which is part of [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx), e.g.

```
$ sigcheck.exe some_app.exe

Sigcheck v2.51 - File version and signature viewer
Copyright (C) 2004-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

C:/Program Files (x86)/Foo App\some_app.exe:
    Verified:   Signed
    Signing date:   14:48 23/12/2015
    Publisher:  X
    Company:    X
    Description:    X
    Product:    Some App
    Prod version:   5.0.0.1241
    File version:   5.0.0.1241
    MachineType:    32-bit
```

---

For older version of Windows such as XP/2k/2003 (it still works in new), use [`filever.exe`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/913111) tool (check the [direct link](http://exedll.info/download/3160_filever.exe) at [exedll.info](http://exedll.info/filever.exe/en-download-3160.html)) to obtain specific information about a file such as:

- The platform on which the file runs
- The version of the file
- The attributes of the file
- The file type
- The language of the file
- Whether the file is a shipping type or a debug type
- The file size
- The date that the file was created
- The path of the file

---

Some other to consider:

- [The Microsoft COFF Binary File Dumper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c(v=vs.100).aspx) (DUMPBIN.EXE)

  > Displays information about Common Object File Format (COFF) binary files. You can use DUMPBIN to examine COFF object files, standard libraries of COFF objects, executable files, and dynamic-link libraries (DLLs).
- [`binwalk`](http://binwalk.org/) - search the specified file(s) for executable opcodes common to a variety of CPU architectures. Easy to use tool for analyzing, reverse engineering, and extracting interesting files/data from binary files.

---

For more commands, check:

- [Command line tool to dump Windows DLL version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/602802/55075)
- [Quick way to tell if an installed application is 64-bit or 32-bit](https://superuser.com/q/103071/87805)

Answer (score 6):

Use the Microsoft's [DUMPBIN utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c(v=vs.100).aspx).

It has lots of useful options, however, it depends on what do you want to do.

However, it's not free, but I believe can be obtained freely with Windows SDK.

Comment: Why isn't it free if it can be obtained freely with the SDK?

Answer (score 3):

```vb
Function GetProductVersion (sFilePath, sProgram)  
Dim objShell, objFolder, objFolderItem, i  
If FSO.FileExists(sFilePath & "\" & sProgram) Then  
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")  
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(sFilePath)  
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(sProgram)  
    Dim arrHeaders(300)  
    For i = 0 To 300  
        arrHeaders(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, i)  
        'WScript.Echo i &"- " & arrHeaders(i) & ": " & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, i)  
        If lcase(arrHeaders(i))= "product version" Then  
            GetProductVersion= objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, i)  
            Exit For  
        End If  
    Next  
End If  
End Function
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976734/how-to-retrieve-a-files-product-version-in-vbscript) is a link to a .vbs file that can get the file version for you, and you can take that and use the output however you want.

Ships will all versions of windows, not sure about the license, very portable, but not exe or DLL.

Comment: There's a couple of answers there, I'm not sure which one you mean. However, I tried some of them, they seem to have path to notepad.exe hard-coded. Is there an easy way to wrap them up so that they accept path to dll/exe as a parameter? Preferably outputting to standard output?

Comment: It takes a path as a parameter, and the product version is contained in `GetProductVersion`

Answer (score 1):

When I initially looked into this problem area, I found that using simple commands like `(Get-Item -Path "C:\path\to\file.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion` — as suggested in the answers of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686/get-file-version-in-powershell) — didn't work reliably across all executables (empty return value). I also noticed that Explorer *does* reliably display the values in a given executable's Properties sheet, so I decided to construct a Powershell function to mimic what Explorer (presumbaly) does to retrieve the properties.

Here's a Powershell function to retrieve all extended properties, including Product Version.

```
function Get-AllExtendedProperties {
    param (
        [string]$FilePath
    )
    If (-not $FilePath) {
        Throw "Error: missing `$FilePath parameter"
    }
    $file = Get-Item $FilePath
    If ($file -and $file.Exists) {
        $parentFolder = Split-Path $file.FullName -Parent
        $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
        $folder = $shell.Namespace($parentFolder)
        $fileItem = $folder.ParseName($file.Name)
        # Get all extended properties
        $extendedProperties = @{}
        For ($i = 0; $i -lt 300; $i++) {
            $propertyValue = $folder.GetDetailsOf($fileItem, $i)
            if ($propertyValue) {
                $propertyName = $folder.GetDetailsOf($folder.Items, $i)
                $extendedProperties[$propertyName] = $propertyValue
            }
        }
        # Sort the hashtable by property name
        $sortedExtendedProperties = $extendedProperties.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object { $_.Key = $_.Key.Trim(); $_ }
        Write-Output $sortedExtendedProperties
    } Else {
        Throw "Error: missing file"
    }
}
```

**Usage**

The simplest way to use this function is to copy/paste it into a Powershell window and press <kbd>Return ↵</kbd>. Then you can use it like this:

```
Get-AllExtendedProperties -FilePath "C:\path\to\file.exe"
```

If you want to get a specific property's value, such as the Product Version, use it like this:

```
Get-AllExtendedProperties -FilePath "C:\path\to\file.exe" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Product Version'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is the way to go. You can:

1. run cmd.exe as the Administrator/Domain Admin user that has local admin rights on the remote server.
2. start "\\C$"    or which ever drive share and folder you need to inspect.
3. Powershell.exe
4. PS C:\Windows\System32> (Get-Item "umrdp.dll").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
   10.0.18362.752